# why path::root_name() has different behavior with <filesystem> and <experimental/filesystem>

Tags: c++, c++17, std-filesystem

For last couple of days I have been experimenting the behavior of few of the functions of `filesystem` and `experimental/filesystem` library.

Note: I ran the code on https://godbolt.org/

below is the code snippet with its output

**1. experimental/filesystem**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <experimental/filesystem>
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;

int main()
{
auto  p = fs::path("//net");
std::cout<<"p = " << p
         <<"\np.root_name= "<< p.root_name()
         <<"\nand p.root_Dir= "<< p.root_directory()
         <<"\np.is_absolute= "<<p.is_absolute()<<std::endl;
}
```

**output:**

```
p = "//net"    
p.root_name= "//net"    
and p.root_Dir= ""    
p.is_absolute= 0
```

[image]
**2. filesystem**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
 
int main()
{
auto  p = fs::path("//net");
std::cout<<"p = " << p
         <<"\np.root_name= "<< p.root_name()
         <<"\nand p.root_Dir= "<< p.root_directory()
         <<"\np.is_absolute= "<<p.is_absolute()<<std::endl;
}
```

**output:**

```
p = "//net"
p.root_name= ""
and p.root_Dir= "/"
p.is_absolute= 1
```

Is there any way to look into the implementation of these functions ?

[image]

Comment: warning: std::experimental::filesystem has now been deprecated in favor of C++17's std::filesystem. Please stop using it and start using std::filesystem. This experimental version will be removed in LLVM 11.

Comment: Search for the source code of the lib and look it up there.

Comment: Yes, I know it will be deprecated . But I want to know why the behaviour is different?

Comment: Because they were experimenting? What's the point in worrying about it.

Comment: if experimental was supposed to be exactly like the final, it wouldn't need to exist. Don't be surprised if something called "experimental" is in an experimental state

Comment: Then which one is the correct behaviour?

Comment: @PraveerKumar the one which you are getting in the second one... On the latest experimental version of LLVM, I am [not even able to reproduce](https://wandbox.org/permlink/UcrvtzAnE9xa5N0t) the first output! They have made a revision somewhere in between previous release and the upcoming one...